How to combine same column and same row dfs into new df with just one category?
I'm new to pandas and I'm trying to aggregate some data, so please excuse this question if it's basic. I looked at many previous posts but cannot seem to find a solution.
I have multiple dfs that share the same row index and column index values, and I'm trying to aggregate them. Its the same structure per se, just different values of data for different days.
For example I have many different csv files with the below same rows and columns:
            Hi Temp    Low Temp    Median Temp   
New York      90         -10          62
Chicago       88         -20          55
Los Angeles   85         -15          68

What I'd like to do is to load a month worth of csv files so 31 files, each per day. I want to create separate df specific to New York_Hi_Temp,New York Low Temp for all 31 days only. so it would look like
New York Hi_Temp | New York Low Temp
70                   25
60                   15
50                   35
40                   55
30                   24
20                   15


import pandas as pd

# Example file paths (you can adjust this to match your actual file paths)
csv_files = ["day1.csv", "day2.csv"]

# Load all CSV files into a list of DataFrames then concat them into one Data Frame
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in csv_files]
df = pd.concat(dfs)

# filter out all for New York
df = df[df["City"] == "New York"] 
#selecting the columns that you want from the df and setting the index to City Column
df = df[["City", "Hi Temp", "Low Temp"]].set_index("City"))

Example for df
          Hi Temp  Low Temp
City                       
New York       90       -10
New York       21       -5

